# Selenium & PHPUnit: How to assert relative location of elements on a web page?

Tags: php, selenium, xpath, phpunit, element

I am using PHPUnit and Selenium server (not using WebDriver) and I want to test a drop down menu. I want to check if my elements drop down in the correct order when I click on it. I can use XPath to check that but if there are any changes on that same page XPath will change and my tests will fail. Does anyone else know any better way for testing this?